# How to attach the git commit sha to a cloud function during deployment in gcp

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cicd

I want to set the git commit sha and attach it to a cloud function during deployment. The only option I got is using environment variables.

Now how to set a variable for a particular function. For example if we use the GCP UI in cloud functions we can edit the source code and also add a Runtime variable to that function which is applicable only to that cloud function even if we have 100s of other CFs.
But from firebase deploy command we don't have anything like

```
firebase deploy --only functions:function1 commit_id=sha
```

By setting config we set this for all the functions which is not what I am looking. I want to set a variable or tag or label to a particular cloud function only.

Please let me know if there is any other way I can do this .

Comment: Not sure to understand. Do you want to add a label on your cloud functions (for functions admin only) or the commit sha in the runtime code to use it in your code?